# Profile Edit errors. If you guys can spot additional errors that would be super cool

Tags: python, flask, web, profile

I am trying to grab and display an image and storing it to a mongodb server so that it can be called again for the profile itself. I am having a filename error. Any help is greatly appreciated:

```
@application.route("/profileEdit", methods = ["POST", "GET"])
def profileEdit():
    if request.method == "POST":

        username = request.form['username']
        password = request.form['password']
        email = request.form['email']
        labor = request.form['image']
        phone = request.form['phone']
        

        if 'file' not in request.files:
            flash('No file part')
            return redirect(request.url)

        file = request.files['file']

        if file.filename == '':
            flash('No image selected for uploading')
            return redirect(request.url)
        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            file.save(os.path.join('/static/Images', filename))
            #print('upload_image filename: ' + filename)
            usersDB = client["userRegistration"]
            users = usersDB['userregistrations']

            #existing_user = users.find_one({'name': request.form['username']}) #update to session
            #if existing_user is None:
                #return redirect(url_for('registration'))

             #else:

            #hashpass = bcrypt.hashpw(password.encode('utf-8'), bcrypt.gensalt())
            #users.updateOne({'date': str(date.today()),'name': username, 'password':hashpass, 'email': email, 'phonenumber': phone, 'labor':labor, 'profilePic': profilePic})
            #session['username'] = request.form['username']
            #return redirect(url_for('profile'))

        else:
            flash('Allowed image types are - png, jpg, jpeg, gif')
            return redirect(request.url)


        
    
    return render_template("profileEdit.html", filename = filename)#, image_file = image_file)

@app.route('/display/<filename>')
def display_image(filename):
    #print('display_image filename: ' + filename)
    return redirect(url_for('static', filename='/static/Images' + filename), code=301)
```

and for the html I have this:

```
 <Form method = "POST">
        {% if filename %}
        <div>
            <img src ="{{ url_for('display_image', filename=filename) }}">
        </div>
        {% endif %}
        
        <dl>
            <p>
                <input type="file" name="file" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" required>
            </p>
        </dl>
      

        <p>
            {% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %}
              {% if messages %}
                <ul>
                {% for message in messages %}
                  <li>{{ message }}</li>
                {% endfor %}
                </ul>
              {% endif %}
            {% endwith %}
        </p>
```

here is the new error ( I forgot to reload it):

```
* Running on http://hidden/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
hidden - - [14/Nov/2021 18:39:13] "GET /profileEdit HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\tquig\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\FS-CSCI150-F21-Team4\env\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2091, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Users\tquig\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\FS-CSCI150-F21-Team4\env\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2076, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\tquig\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\FS-CSCI150-F21-Team4\env\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2073, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\tquig\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\FS-CSCI150-F21-Team4\env\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1518, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\tquig\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\FS-CSCI150-F21-Team4\env\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1516, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\tquig\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\FS-CSCI150-F21-Team4\env\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1502, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args)
  File "C:\Users\tquig\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\FS-CSCI150-F21-Team4\application.py", line 158, in profileEdit
    return render_template("profileEdit.html", filename = filename)#, image_file = image_file)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'filename' referenced before assignment
```

Thank you guys at stack overflow you guys are awesome!

Comment: The variable `filename` will only be set if `request.method == 'POST'` and `file` is true and `allowed_file` is true, but all your other cases still fall through to the `return` statement.

Comment: So you are saying it isn't being set because I have barriers before it being set?

Comment: I put the line of setting the variable underneath the file variable set. That fixed that issue but it isn't displaying the html and css anymore.

Comment: you could set `filename = None` at the beginnig of `profileEdit()` to have this variable all time.